# Angular binding to a read-only property

Tags: angularjs

How do you enforce read-only properties in a performant way in Angular?

Controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.clickCount = 0;
  $scope.incrementCount = function() {
    $scope.clickCount = $scope.clickCount + 1;
  }
}
```

View:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Clicked {{clickCount}} times
  <button ng-click="incrementCount()">Doober</button>
  <input type="text" ng-model="clickCount" /><!-- how do I prevent this -->
</div>
```

I know I could make `clickCount` a getter function `getClickCount()`, but will that kill the performance since Angular will have to call this function on every digest cycle?

http://jsfiddle.net/zb05om1k/

---

### Update

I'm looking for a way that makes it clear that the read only property should not be changed directly but instead through the provided function. Additionally, prevent the view from changing the property directly.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Simply displaying the value of clickCount without allowing a user to edit it?

Comment: How about ngReadonly? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngReadonly

Comment: why you don't think of bindonce directive of angular 1.3+

Comment: I'm looking for a way in the controller to make it clear that `clickCount` should not be changed directly but instead affected through the function.

Comment: Have you measured it? If a simple function would really kill performance, then the function would be your smallest problem. Moreover you simply can make the input read-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `incrementCount()` is called once and takes a negligible amount of time to execute, then Angular starts a digest cycle and the DOM rebuilds, which would happen anyway.

As a general rule, you don't need to optimize code whose time is bound by user input. Your example code looks fine to me.

If you really want to enforce separation of concerns by making the property read-only, you can use [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to prevent writes:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function MyCtrl($scope) {
    var clickCount = 0; // Private variable

    Object.defineProperty($scope, 'clickCount', {
        set: function() { // Prevent views from editing data
            throw new Error('Operation not supported');
        },
        get: function() {
            return clickCount;
        }
    });

    $scope.incrementCount = function() {
        clickCount++;
    }
});
```

When you put data in the input, the controller throws an error and the change is immediately erased in the DOM.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/acbabis/5bq5oeq3/

Answer (score 2):

use the angular directive `ng-readonly`, it works just like it sounds...

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngReadonly

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking for a way that **prevents** views from changing the value directly and instead affecting it through the provided function. I know this particular example is contrived, but I wanted it to be simple.